# Sump Discharge Carry

Tags: sump

I'm trying to figure out the best way (and materials) to carry the sump pump discharge water away so it no longer creates a cesspool beside my garage.

When we moved in 6+ years ago there were old broken down downspouts being used to carry the discharge water up the side of my garage and onto the driveway where it runs off.  The connected downspouts leaked at the seams and were too clogged so nothing came out.

When I tore them out I wanted to originally tie in the sump pump discharge, the garage downspout and install a drain in the yard to catch water at the low point and use an underground pipe to carry the water to the front yard where it grades down.  I'm not sure there is a good place to discharge with an underground pipe(and it would have to run very close to the neighbor's property where they have a mature tree) so that plan has been shelved for the time being but would have been the optimal solution from the effectiveness standpoint.

Back to the original question, what materials should I use? 2.5 in PVC with glued couplings?  I found 2" flexible PVC, would that be a better option?  Is there any way to fasten the pipe so it grades slowly from the back of the house to the front?  Is there a way to fasten the pipe without drilling into my foundation?  I was looking at various hangers and wasn't sure if they could be used upside down in the dirt to hold the pipe at a grade without having to drill into the foundation.

I have a few pictures attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar  project at my son's home so we dug a 100 foot trench about 2 feet deep, the deeper the better, added 12" of gravel (rocks), laid in 4" schedule 35 perforated drain pipe, a little more gravel, and then a layer of top soil. Planted grass seed and all the water drains into the ground. You can not bury a flexible hose but can lay it on top of the ground, YUK.

Comment: the trench is absolutely the best way to go in order to get the water out but the upfront cost, ongoing maintenance and potential pissing yneighbors off are disadvantages. And I don’t really want a pipe sticking out of my front yard if I don’t have to.  Some on the neighborhood have actually cut the curb and put a pipe right there. That was probably a long time ago

Comment: Once I did the trench that I dug by hand and buried the pipe, he never had a problem or more water than the trench could handle. The end of the pipe terminates under ground so you never sees it. This worked for my son

Comment: Thanks.  I don’t think I could bury enough to drain it all. We also have heavy clay which contributes to this problem overall.

Comment: I did the same thing at my grandmother's many years ago, I dug a trench used perf pipe that was in a sock and took it to the sidewalk. We could not directly drain water onto the street there. I covered the trench pipe and gravel with landscaping fabric then replaced the dirt, the water percolates up through the grass and drains into the street, after I did this several neighbors also did the same. The city was called by someone and we found out it was totally legal in that town as long as the pipe was not visible, it was considered a spring. I know this worked for at least 20 years.+

Answer (score 0):

[image: Lay flat PVC discharge hose]

The above is available from Princess Auto -- sort of the Canadian equivalent of Northern Tool.  The 1.5" diameter hose is a CAD$1/foot.

Clamp this to the discharge line  and run it where you will.

Gotchas:  This doesn't work in winter.  If your sump runs in winter, the leftover water freezes in the tubing and your sump can't do much.  You *MUST make sure the water always has a place to go.

I have two systems:  In the summer I use the flat pipe.  In winter I use 2 12 foot lengths of 2" ABS waste line and slide it loosely over the exit pipe.  Then I make sure that the discharge end is supported above the ground (tied to a milk crate)

Since it's a steady slope, not much water remains inthe pipe.

If the pipe does get blocked, the water can escape around the opening at the top.

I also have a 12v pump in the sump, above normal high water.  It uses a garden hose which I route separately.  An alarm sounds if the 12v one goes off.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes the freeze/thaw issue is one reason why I don’t like pvc for this. It will decouple at the seams after 1-2 winters. I’ll see if I can fnd that hose anywhere locally.  I will probably have to build up the mulch so it runs from the back of the house to the front.  

I could use what I’m doing now during The winter. Everything is pieces together possess so I don’t have to worry about it freezing solid.